# Redirect http to https single link

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect 
http://advokatami.bg/wp-content/uploads/2014/napred.png 
to
https://advokatami.bg/wp-content/uploads/2014/napred.png

i am using the http:// ver in Wufoo for my site with SSL, but i have mixed content on that image and i don't want to replace the link in about 100 Wufoo forms.
Is there a way to do it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible: when the browser do the request it's already too late, even if the server answer a redirect.

As a temporary solution you can use https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/